# tf.reduce_mean is not working in tf.function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

**code below**

---

@tf.function

def train_step(self, batch):

```
with tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape, tf.GradientTape() as infe_tape, tf.GradientTape() as gener_tape:
  loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc = self.compute_loss(batch)

  grad_encoder = gener_tape.gradient(loss_encoder, self.model.inference_net.trainable_variables)
  grad_decoder = infe_tape.gradient(loss_decoder, self.model.generative_net.trainable_variables)
  grad_disc = disc_tape.gradient(loss_disc, self.model.discriminator.trainable_variables)

  self.infe_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_encoder, self.model.inference_net.trainable_variables))
  self.genr_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_decoder, self.model.generative_net.trainable_variables))
  self.disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_disc, self.model.discriminator.trainable_variables))

  return loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc
```

---

---

@tf.function

def train(self, epoch):

```
loss_history = tf.zeros([3,0])
for batch in self.train_dataset:
  loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc = self.train_step(batch)
  loss_each = tf.expand_dims(tf.stack([loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc], axis=0), 1)
  loss_history = tf.concat([loss_history, loss_each], axis=1)

mean_loss_encoder, mean_loss_decoder, mean_loss_disc = tf.reduce_mean(loss_history, axis=1)
tf.summary.scalar('encoder loss', data=mean_loss_encoder, step=epoch, description='train_loss')
tf.summary.scalar('decoder loss', data=mean_loss_decoder, step=epoch, description='train_loss')
tf.summary.scalar('discriminator loss', data=mean_loss_disc, step=epoch, description='train_loss')
print('encoder training loss %.5f' % mean_loss_encoder, 'decoder training loss %.5f' % mean_loss_decoder, 'discriminator training loss %.5f' % mean_loss_disc)
```

---

---

@tf.function

def validation_step(self, batch):
     return self.compute_loss(batch, training=tf.constant(False, tf.bool))

---

---

@tf.function

def validation(self, epoch):
    '''produce mean loss for epoch and append to self.val_loss_monior'''

```
loss_history = tf.zeros([3,0])
for batch in self.validation_dataset:
    loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc = self.validation_step(batch)
    loss_each = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([loss_encoder, loss_decoder, loss_disc], axis=0), 1)
    loss_history = tf.concat([loss_history, loss_each], axis=1) 
mean_loss_each = tf.reduce_mean(loss_history, axis=1)
print('encoder validation loss %.5f' % mean_loss_each[0], 'decoder validation loss %.5f' % mean_loss_each[1], 'discriminator validation loss %.5f' % mean_loss_each[2])

tf.summary.scalar('encoder loss', data=mean_loss_each[0], step=epoch, description='val_loss')
tf.summary.scalar('decoder loss', data=mean_loss_each[1], step=epoch, description='val_loss')
tf.summary.scalar('discriminator loss', data=mean_loss_each[2], step=epoch, description='val_loss')

# self.val_loss_monior: (3, self.patience), each row store history loss for each network
loss_each = tf.expand_dims(mean_loss_each, 1)
if epoch + 1 > self.patience:
  is_less =  self.val_loss_monior < loss_each
  is_less_encoder, is_less_decoder, is_less_discriminator = list(map(lambda x: tf.raw_ops.Any(input=tf.cast(tf.squeeze(x), tf.bool), axis=0), tf.split(is_less, 3, axis=0)))

  if not is_less_encoder:
     self.infe_optimizer.learning_rate *= self.decay_rate
  if not is_less_decoder:
     self.genr_optimizer.learning_rate *= self.decay_rate
  if not is_less_discriminator:
     self.disc_optimizer.learning_rate *= self.decay_rate

self.val_loss_monior = tf.slice(self.val_loss_monior, [0, 1], [3, self.patience - 1])
self.val_loss_monior = tf.concat([self.val_loss_monior, loss_each], axis=1)

tf.summary.scalar('encoder learning rate', data=self.infe_optimizer.learning_rate, step=epoch)
tf.summary.scalar('decoder learning rate', data=self.genr_optimizer.learning_rate, step=epoch)
tf.summary.scalar('discriminator learning rate', data=self.disc_optimizer.learning_rate, step=epoch)
```

---

---

@tf.function

def fit(self):

```
self.val_loss_monitor = tf.zeros([3, self.patience])
for epoch in range(self.epochs):
  start = time.time()
  epoch = tf.cast(epoch, tf.int64)
  self.train(epoch)
  self.validation(epoch)

  print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch, time.time()-start))
  display.clear_output(wait=True)
  if (epoch + 1) % 5 == 0:
    self.generate_images(epoch)
```

---

**error massage below**

---

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

```
<ipython-input-5-8af39e045349>:152 fit  *
    self.train(epoch)
<ipython-input-5-8af39e045349>:90 train  *
    mean_loss_encoder, mean_loss_decoder, mean_loss_disc = tf.reduce_mean(loss_history, axis=1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:561 __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:554 _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:532 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
    " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

---

The problem should be

---

mean_loss_encoder, mean_loss_decoder, mean_loss_disc = tf.reduce_mean(loss_history, axis=1)

---

Error is about iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed.
Is reduce_mean not working in tf.function?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`a = tf.reduce_mean(loss_history, axis=1)`
, if want to use tensor element, use a[0], a[1], ..., it works.
It look like that tensor can not catch separately.